# Image Poisson Noise on image in double precision (shot noise)

Tags: matlab, noise, poisson

I am trying to add poisson noise to an image with doulbe precision. I do:

```
I = im2double(imread('mypic.tif')); % mypic.tif is already in the range 0...1 in double precision
J = imnoise(I,'poisson');
imshow(I),figure,imshow(J);
```

I see that both `I` and `J` are pretty the same. What I am doing wrong?
Please note I do know that imnoise scales the value by 1e-12 but sincerly I don't understand how to use it correctly.

I was thinking I could use `poissrnd()` to add noise manually to bypass `imnoise`

Regarding the scaling i was using a [code like this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242444#621859):

```
maxValue = max(I(:));

% This is necessary based on imnoise behaviour
I = I * 10e-12;

% Generate noisy image and scale back to the original intensities. 
J = maxValue * imnoise(I, 'poisson');
```

But it returns an image almost completly black.

Comment: Keep in mind that the vast majority of images have an 8-bit depth per channel (red, blue, green, gray, etc.), meaning 256 distinct values, even if mapped to `0..1`. In order to make a difference in a pixel, the noise threshhold must be > 1/256 ~= 4e-3. If your Poisson source is really scaled to 1e-12, that's *way* below the threshhold...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the link says, this is a large number problem.

Try using a smaller scale:

```
I = im2double(imread('eight.tif')); %Matlab default image
scale = 1e9;
J = scale * imnoise(I/scale, 'poisson'); 
close all; imshow(J);
```

Input:

[image]

Output (1e9):

[image]

Output (1e10):

[image]

Comment: The docmentation about this is pretty vague. Thanks anyway I will try

Comment: Now it's working! But, could you explain it? Why we need to divide the image by that scale?

Comment: scaling it by this factor brings the noise to a level where it has some effect on the image, see @twalberg's comment

Comment: I see. Do I have any way to calc the right scale factor based on my image?